# How do you connect 2 ComboBoxes to different tables?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to setup a form, which has 2 ComboBoxes on, each attached to different tables in the database.
Once the user has made a selection in each ComboBox, I want to then query another table to list all of the items that meet the criteria.
I have so far got this to work with 1 ComboBox, but the second ComboBox does not connect to the database.
I am unsure how to add the additional ComboBox to the code. The button at the moment only displays the output from 1 ComboBox, but I will change this to save the values in memory and open a new window to display the results of the query.

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class frmSecond
    'Private MyDatAdp As New SqlDataAdapter '
    'Private MyDataTbl As New DataTable '
    'Private MyRowPosition As Integer = 0 '
    Private Sub frmSecond_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim connectionString As String = Nothing
        connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-S7FRNAL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Verses_Find;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim command As SqlCommand
        Dim sql As String = Nothing
        Dim adaptor As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        sql = "Select SID, EVENT from Event_Type"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            adaptor.SelectCommand = command
            adaptor.Fill(ds)
            adaptor.Dispose()
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()
            ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = "SID"
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Event"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Can't open connection")
        End Try

        connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-S7FRNAL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Verses_Find;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sql1 As String = Nothing
        Dim ds1 As New DataSet()
        sql1 = "Select BID, EVENT_Sub from Sub_Event"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Try
            connection.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand(sql1, connection)
            adaptor.SelectCommand = command
            adaptor.Fill(ds1)
            adaptor.Dispose()
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()
            ComboBox2.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
            ComboBox2.ValueMember = "BID"
            ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Event_Sub"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Can't open 2nd connection")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(ComboBox1.Text + " --" + ComboBox1.DisplayMember)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This did not work!
It only connected to the first combo, and displayed  not connected to the 2nd combo and exception error reported can't find or missing PDB file.
I am inexperienced and elderly, so could do with some help.

Comment: When you step through your code in the debugger, which line causes error? I think the problem is that your are reusing objects after disposing them. Try creating new adaptor and command for the second connection.

Comment: Also examine a better pattern for doing your job with "Using" statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Your `adaptor` (SqlDataAdapter) is re-used while being disposed of. Thus, the code flow ends up in your second `Catch`. The *missing PDB* is just a side-effect. `New` the SqlDataAdapter as you did with Connecton and Command. Here, declaring all the objects in `Using` blocks, as AlexVB suggested, would be a good thing. Btw, the `DataAdapter` opens the Connection for you.